# How can I query nuget.org for metainfo

Tags: .net, nuget, nuspec

I need to find out some specific metainformation like hash, license, author for a specific version of a package without downloading it.
I already found out about the existence of a web api but dont know how to really use it.
If I query something like this:
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='package.name.here'
I get a large xml document conatining many information which is nice.
Is there a way to further tailor my query to only send me the metainformation which i really need?

Comment: Filter it, show some code.

Comment: I hnow how to extract the information from the big xml file. What I am looking for is a way to get a smaller, more relevant xml file by building a more tailored URL. Dont know enough about the Web api how to to this.